# Complicated Drush setup with MAMP

Tags: 7, drush

Since two weeks I have replaced my optical hard drive with an SSD for my OS and all my applications while I kept my hard drive for data. So I've installed MAMP on my SSD and my Drupal directory (workspace within Eclipse) is on the Macintosh HD.

So,
Path to MAMP: `/SSD/Applications/MAMP`
Path to Drupal: `/Macintosh\ HD/Users/me/Documents/workspace/drupal`

I've put the drush folder `/Macintosh\ HD/Users/me/Documents/workspace/drush` and drush is working just fine, but for some reason, whenever I download a module by using drush, the module ends up in my homefolder while it should be using my Drupal folder I think, right?

How can I fix this and make drush work with my Drupal directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a aliases.drushrc.php file to specify project details.

Create an `aliases.drushrc.php` file in one of the following places:

1. /etc/drush
2. $HOME/.drush

If you don't have `/etc` for `/etc/drush` perhaps it would work in: `/Macintosh\ HD/Users/me/Documents/workspace/drush`

`aliases.drushrc.php` contents

```
<?php
$aliases['dev'] = array(
  'uri' => 'dev.example.com',
  'root' => '/Macintosh HD/Users/me/Documents/workspace/drupal',
);

// or perhaps root with the escaped space char '/Macintosh\ HD/Users/me/Documents/workspace/drupal'
```

then from anywhere in the filesystem, you should be able to go

- drush @dev dl views
- drush @dev sqlc
- drush @dev updb

etc..

Fully commented example drush aliases file [here](http://drush.ws/examples/example.aliases.drushrc.php)

Comment: Thx for the tip. I'm running my sites on localhost, so what should be the URI? I'm using MAMP, so my URL is `http://localhost:8888/drupal_test/`...

Comment: In Drupal 6, your uri should be the same as it is on the live site (e.g. 'example.com'); otherwise, you may have problems. For Drupal 7 this is not an issue, so you can set your uri to something convenient for your dev site, such as 'localhost:8888'.  This will allow commands such as `drush uli` to work correctly.